# How to name a truth table (array)

Tags: tables, arrays

I am trying to name a truth table, which I made by using the "displaymath" and "array" commands. I want to know how can I name it as "Table 1: etc..." I tried using the caption command but I get an error "caption outside of float"

This is the code

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, subcaption, setspace, booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage[english, spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{url, lipsum}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[nodayofweek,level]{datetime}
\usepackage{caption}
\newcommand{\mydate}{\formatdate{31}{8}{2017}}
\newcommand{\HRule}[1]{\rule{\linewidth}{#1}}
\onehalfspacing
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\setlength\headheight{15pt}
\fancyhead[L]{Carné: B31791}
\fancyhead[R]{Universidad de Costa Rica}
\fancyfoot[R]{Página \thepage\ de \pageref{LastPage}}


\begin{document}

\title{ \normalsize \textsc{Circuitos Digitales 1}
        \\ [2.0cm]
        \HRule{0.5pt} \\
        \LARGE \textbf{\uppercase{Tarea 1}}
        \HRule{2pt} \\ [0.5cm]
        \normalsize \selectlanguage{spanish} \mydate \vspace*{5\baselineskip}}

\date{}

\author{
        Carné: B31791 \\ 
        Universidad de Costa Rica \\
        Escuela de Ingeniería Eléctrica }

\maketitle

\newpage


\sectionfont{\scshape}


\section*{Tablas de verdad}

Se realizaron varias tablas de verdad para apreciar de manera concisa lo realizado en cada etapa del proceso. La primera tabla de verdad muestra cómo se realiza la suma de los \textit{LSB} de los números A y B junto con el ${{\rm{C}}_{{\rm{in}}}}$ (carry in) . Se utiliza la conectiva \textit{XOR} para la suma:

\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{|c c|c c|}
% |c c|c| means that there are three columns in the table and
% a vertical bar ’|’ will be printed on the left and right borders,
% and between the second and the third columns.
% The letter ’c’ means the value will be centered within the column,
% letter ’l’, left-aligned, and ’r’, right-aligned.
{{\rm{A}}_{\rm{0}}} & {{\rm{B}}_{\rm{0}}} & {{\rm{S}}_0} & {{\rm{C}}_{{\rm{in}}}}\\ % Use & to separate the columns
\hline % Put a horizontal line between the table header and the rest.
0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
\captionof{table}{Suma de los \textit{LSB}}
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}


La siguiente tabla de verdad contiene la suma de los \textit{MSB} de los números a sumar, el



\end{document}
```

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please extend your code sniped to complete small document beginning with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with`\end{document}`. if you use `caption` package, the solution can be `\captionof{table}{ <title of table >}`.

Comment: I still get an error if I put inside the "displaymath" environment. If I put it ouside, which works, looks strange because it way below the table.

Comment: caption had to be outside math environment, of course. please again, edit your question and show what you try so far that i can help you.

Comment: Finished editing the code

Answer (score 1):

[image]

- solution without using float `table`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{center}
\captionof{table}{My important table}
\label{tab:array}
$
\begin{array}{|c c|c c|}
\mathrm{A}_{\mathrm{0}} & \mathrm{B}_{\rm{0}}   & \mathrm{S}_0  & \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{in}}  \\
\hline % Put a horizontal line between the table header and the rest.
    0                   &   0                   &   0           &   0                       \\
    0                   &   1                   &   1           &   0                       \\
    1                   &   0                   &   1           &   0                       \\
    1                   &   1                   &   0           &   1                       \\
\end{array}
$
\end{center}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```

- solution with using float `table`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{My important table}
\label{tab:array}
\[
\begin{array}{|c c|c c|}
\mathrm{A}_{\mathrm{0}} & \mathrm{B}_{\rm{0}}   & \mathrm{S}_0  & \mathrm{C}_{\mathrm{in}}  \\
\hline % Put a horizontal line between the table header and the rest.
    0                   &   0                   &   0           &   0                       \\
    0                   &   1                   &   1           &   0                       \\
    1                   &   0                   &   1           &   0                       \\
    1                   &   1                   &   0           &   1                       \\
\end{array}
\]
\end{table}
\lipsum[2]
\end{document}
```