# Add a caption after an array inside displaymath

Tags: captions, arrays

I'm writing truth tables like this:

```
\begin{displaymath}
\begin{array}{|c c|c|}
p & q & p \land q \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\end{displaymath}
```

and I'd like to put a caption after the table explaining what the table is.
I've tried both with `\caption`and `captionof`but it won't compile.

Comment: Maybe a side caption would be more appropriate.

Comment: Probably you are interested in Zarko's answer to this question: [How to name a truth table (array)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/388543/134144). Included are two possibilities using either a floating `table` environment and the `\caption` command or a non-floating `center` environment in combination with the `\captionof` command.

Comment: Please clarify what ”it doesn’t compile” entail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage{mathtools,amssymb}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

\bgroup\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{-2ex}
\begin{gather*}
\begin{array}{|cc|c|}
p & q & p \land q \\
\hline
1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\shortintertext{%
\captionof{table}{This is my table with caption}}
\end{gather*}
\egroup
Some text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text. Some more text.

\end{document}
```

[image]